# how to migrate Docker Registry from file system to S3 storage?

Tags: docker-registry

I am using the [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) with the [filesystem storage driver](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/registry/storage-drivers/filesystem.md). What I want to do is to migrate that existing Registry to S3-compatible storage without loosing data.

While I could pull all images on a dedicated client, reconfigure the registry and push again, I would like to find a more *direct* approach because of the size and amount of already stored Images.

Is there any way to migrate the data from filesystem to S3 without having to re-push the Images?

Comment: How to you expect the data to be available from S3 without pushing it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging it turned out that a [storage driver](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/32ac467/registry/storage/driver/storagedriver.go) is just a filesystem abstraction, so all that needed to be done to migrate a Docker Registry from filesystem to S3 is to copy the content of the registry's directory unaltered to S3.